# How to construct sub arrays from a main array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to construct sub n number of arrays from  a multi dimensional array depends on the data. For example:  I have a main array as

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [status] => -1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [status] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [status] => 2
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [status] => 2
        )
)
```

I would like to get 3 arrays from this array depends on the no and type of status value 
like

```
  array{
    [0]=array(
        [status]=-1
        [count]=1

    )
    [1]=array(
        [status]=1
        [count]=1

    )
    [2]=array(
        [status]=2
        [count]=3

    )

}
```

Thanks in advance,

Sunil Kumar P

Comment: What have tried? What is your specific problem in using a loop?

Comment: [0]=array( or [0]=>array( ?? typo ??

Comment: @sunil not possible to keep same keys 0 for all three

Comment: I am looking for a solution for an unlimited sub array result. I mean the no of sub arrays will be equal to the status types. Now there is only 3 status types like -1,1 and 2. If there is n no of status types, then we need to get n sub arrays having status type field and status count....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?:

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'status' => -1),
    array('id' => 2, 'status' => 1),
    array('id' => 3, 'status' => 2),
    array('id' => 4, 'status' => 2),
    array('id' => 5, 'status' => 2)
);


$statuses = array();
foreach($array as $one){
    if(!isset($statuses[$one['status']])){ $statuses[$one['status']] = 0; }
    $statuses[$one['status']]++;
}

$newArray = array();
foreach($statuses as $key => $val){
    $newArray[] = array('status' => $key, 'count' => $val);
}

print_r($newArray);


/*Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => -1
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => 2
            [count] => 3
        )

)*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your time . I mean I would like to construct a chart for the user status . So I would like to get the no of each user status. The main array contains all users , and I would like to get each user status and the count. Hope that you got the idea now. Thanks in advance

Comment: what I made does exactly what you want .. I don't understand what more ?